# Using SOAP to generate XML attributes in PHP

Tags: php, soap

I found you can generate this in SOAP in php:

```
<foo bar="blah">12345</foo>
```

With this:

```
array("foo" => array("_" => 12345, "bar" => "blah"));
```

However, the underscore method does not seem to work when the value is not a number and string, but instead *embedded xml code*.  How would you do this for instance?

```
<foo bar="blah">
    <aaa a="b">blah</aaa>
</foo>
```

This is an extension of this person's question:
http://www.bigresource.com/Tracker/Track-php-uQwDoUib/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't have a quick way of testing, but maybe this would work:

```
$a = array(
    'foo' => array(
        'bar' => 'blah',
        'aaa' => array(
            '_' => 'blah',
            'a' => "b",
        ),
    ),  
);
```

Answer (score 1):

How can you add an attribute to a node that is the function;

```
$update = $soap->UpdateMember($pRecord);
```

or

```
$update = $soap->__soapCall('UpdateMember', array($Updates));
```

I need to add namescape or xmlns attribute to the actual function name here. I'm getting the following;

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.sample.net/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:UpdateMember>
MORE XML HERE
</ns1:UpdateMember>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

but I need

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.sample.net/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:UpdateMember xmlns="http://www.sample.net/">
MORE XML HERE
</ns1:UpdateMember>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Need to have ns1:UpdateMember xmlns:ns1="http://www.sample.net/" or something like that.

Comment: Hi. Did you solve this? I'm working around this, if you have any idea it could help me. Thanks!

Comment: Probably, but to be honest I don't even recall how or where I have that code.