# Using SOAP to generate XML attributes in PHP

Tags: php, soap, attributes

I need to generate the following XML with SOAP:

```
<MetaDataConstraint class="topics">
     <Value>FRX</Value>
</MetaDataConstraint>
```

I am not sure how to generate the attributes.

Based on: [Using SOAP to generate XML attributes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045850/using-soap-to-generate-xml-attributes-in-php), I tried to do the following, but unfortunatelly it does not work.

$myFilter = array("MetaDataConstraint" => array("_" => array("Value" => "FRX")),
       "class" => "topics");

How can I solve it ?

Comment: Do you simply need to create the XML structure to send via a SOAP operation?? In other words, are you only really needing this XML layout in a simple PHP string variable? Apologies if I have misunderstood, but I am trying to get more clarity on the questions.

Comment: I seem to have misunderstood, sorry, after reading the link you posted I get where you're coming from, and will see what I can muster up.

Comment: Well, what I need to do is the following:
    $headlinesArray = array(
   'TimeOut' => "600",
   'MaxCount' => "10",
   'MaxCountPerFilter' => "true",
   'StartTime' => "2010-08-10T00:00:00",
   'EndTime' => "2010-08-12T00:00:00",
   'Direction' => "Newer", 
   'Filter' => $myFilter
);

$myRequest = array(
   'HeadlineMLRequest' => $headlinesArray
);

and then:
$myResponse = $client2->__soapCall('RetrieveHeadlineML_1', array('parameters' => $myRequest), null, $myHeaders);

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->class = "topics";
$obj->Value = "FRX";
$myfilter = $obj;
```