# building a php object equal to xml tag

Tags: php, xml

i am developing an app in php it pulls data from Reuters API i am trying to add the request parameters before making SOAP call , i have the xml which must be generated from my request it must look like this :

```
<HeadlineMLRequest>
<Filter>
<MetaDataConstraint class="companies"  xmlns="http://schemas.reuters.com/ns/2006/04/14/rmds/webservices/news/filter">
<Value>MSFT.O</Value>
</MetaDataConstraint>
</Filter>
</HeadlineMLRequest>
```

when i build my request parameter object i tried this

```
protected function getRequest() {
$retval->HeadlineMLRequest->MaxCount = 10;
$retval->HeadlineMLRequest->Filter->MetaDataConstraint->class = "companies";
$retval->HeadlineMLRequest->Filter->MetaDataConstraint->Value = "MSFT.O";
return $retval;
}
```

but when i echo last xml request i find it like this

```
<ns1:headlinemlrequest>
<ns1:maxcount>
 10
</ns1:maxcount>
<ns1:filter>
 <ns2:metadataconstraint class="companies">
  <ns2:value>
  </ns2:value>
 </ns2:metadataconstraint>
</ns1:filter>
```

if you notice Value is empty although i set it with "MSFT.O" , any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Complex requests with php soap are not well documented and most examples show only basic techniques.

Try the following:

```
$metaData = '<MetaDataConstraint class="companies" xmlns="http://schemas.reuters.com/ns/2006/04/14/rmds/webservices/news/filter">
<Value>MSFT.O</Value>
</MetaDataConstraint>';

$xmlvar = new SoapVar($metaData, XSD_ANYXML);
$retval->HeadlineMLRequest->Filter->MetaDataConstraint = $xmlVar;
```

Comment: someone already asked a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467624/using-soap-to-generate-xml-attributes-in-php)