# PHP soap client request elements

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I am attempting to create a SOAP request that would in part have the following:

```
<com:locale language="?" country="?">
                     <com:descriptions>

                        <com:description type="?">This is a description</com:description>
                     </com:descriptions>
                     <com:marketingDescription>This is a marketing des</com:marketingDescription>
```

I am able to add the attributes just fine using the following:

```
function buildTask($db, $id=1) {
$task = array(
    'id' => $id++,
    'insertCustomProduct' => array(
                                    'manufacturerId' => "1234567",
                                    'manufacturerPartNo' => "ABC12345",

                                    'categoryId' => 10000000,
                                    'categoryType' => 'default',  
                                    'skus' => array(
                                                    'sku' => array(
                                                                    'type' => 'Internal',
                                                                    'number' => "123456ff",
                                                                    ),
                                                    ),
                                    'locales' => array(
                                                    'locale' => array(
                                                                    'language' => 'EN',
                                                                    'country' => 'US',
                                                                    'descriptions' => array(
                                                                                            'description' => array("type"=>1,
                                                                                                                    "CustomDescription"=>"This is a test")
                                                                                      ),
          'marketingDescription' => "This is the test Marketing Text",
        ),
      ),
    )
  );
```

I am having a problem with passing the non-attribute values such as the actual description and the Marketing text

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

The little documented "_" array key should give you the value of part of the XML (found in a comment [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php#90161) and mention on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045850/using-soap-to-generate-xml-attributes-in-php)). In your example something along these lines - untested of course:

```php
function buildTask($db, $id=1) {
$task = array(
    'id' => $id++,
    'insertCustomProduct' => array(
        'manufacturerId' => "1234567",
        'manufacturerPartNo' => "ABC12345",
        'categoryId' => 10000000,
        'categoryType' => 'default',  
        'skus' => array(
            'sku' => array(
                'type' => 'Internal',
                'number' => "123456ff",
                ),
            ),
        'locales' => array(
                'locale' => array(
                'language' => 'EN',
                'country' => 'US',
                'descriptions' => array(
                    'description' => array("type"=>1,
                                    "_"=>"This is a test")
                                              ),
                'marketingDescription' => array( "_" => "This is the test Marketing Text"),
            ),
        ),
    )
  );
```

Comment: I have tried this - but it doesn't seem to work at all
`'descriptions' => array(
                                                                                            'description' => array('_'=>'test Desc',
                                                                                                                    'type'=>'11')
                                                                                      ),
                                                                    'marketingDescription' => array('_'=>"This is the test Marketing Text")`

Comment: Maybe some more information on how you are building the SOAP request would help? Are you using SoapClient? Is there a WSDL?

Comment: Yes I am using the SOAP client as well as a wsdl - I am able to get everything else to work except for this bit - the XML attributes are generated fine - it's just the non-attribute values that I am having trouble with